# Setting up jest tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using jest to run unit tests on a tool that generates YAML and JSON, it's not pure javascript. Jest allows me to actually tests the values in the output, so it's super convenient.

I have a directory, components:

```
/workdir/components/
├── component1
└── component2
```

And in each of those components, I have a test directory with some jest tests in it. Here's an example test:

```
// Define tests for component
//
const _ = require("lodash");
const componentName = 'my_component';
const {
    getTestEnvironmentComponents
} = require("../../../lib/testHelpers.js");

const component = getTestEnvironmentComponents(componentName);


test("Checking array properties", () => {
  expect(Array.isArray(component)).toBe(true);
  expect(component).toHaveLength(2);
});
```

Inside `testHelpers.js` I have this:

```
module.exports = {
  getTestEnvironmentComponents: function (component) {
    const contents = require('.././components/'+component+'/tmp/test-manifest.json');
    return contents;
  },
  },
};
```

So I have a helper script which expects there to be a generated JSON file inside the component directory.

Now, I need to generate that JSON file before every test and for each component. What makes this difficult is that the method of generating that JSON file differs for each component. When I was doing the testing for a single component, I simply added a `jest.config.js` to the component like so:

```
module.exports = {
  globalSetup: "./test/0-setup.js",
  verbose: true,
};
```

And then defined the `0-setup.js` for the test like so:

```
// This file is the "globalSetup" file.
// FIXME: make this global somehow
module.exports = () => {
    const execa = require("execa");
    const fs = require("fs");
    const path = require("path");

    const command = "generate-json";
    const output = execa.shellSync(command);
    const testEnvironmentOutput = JSON.parse(output.stdout);

    if (!fs.existsSync("./tmp")) {
        fs.mkdirSync("./tmp");
    }

    fs.writeFileSync('./tmp/test-manifest.json', JSON.stringify(testEnvironmentOutput));
};
```

This works for one component, but it means in order to run my `jest` tests, I have to cd into every single component and run jest individually.

So:

- Is there a way to define the setup tasks inside the component directory?
- Is there perhaps a better way of doing this so that I can run `jest` from within the root directory, and it will traverse the subtrees and run the setup tasks some other way?

Comment: Any reason why all the setup work can't be done in a [`beforeAll`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeallfn-timeout) in the test file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, and it might be the solution - can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to do a bunch of work on a test-by-test basis before the tests within the test file run.

That sounds like the perfect use of [`beforeAll`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeallfn-timeout).

Here is a highly simplified example:

```
const componentName = 'my_component';

let component;

beforeAll(async () => {
  doSomePrepWork();
  await doSomethingAsync();
  doSomeMorePrepWork();
  component = getTestEnvironmentComponents(componentName);
});

test("Checking array properties", () => {
  expect(Array.isArray(component)).toBe(true);
  expect(component).toHaveLength(2);
});
```

`Jest` will run `beforeAll` before *any* of the tests run, so you can use it to do setup work for all the tests in a test file.

**Helpful note**: If you need to do asynchronous work in `beforeAll` you can pass it an `async` function (or pass it a normal function that returns a `Promise`), and it will **wait** for the resulting `Promise` to resolve before allowing `Jest` to continue to the tests.

Comment: I gave this a try, and unfortunately my tests just seemed to hang forever where the changes were made, so I'm obviously doing something wrong :(